# How to remove a reel in which I'm tagged as collaborator from my profile, without removing me as collaborator?

Tags: instagram

Let's say I'm selective about what shows up in my profile grid. But in a reel posted by someone else featuring me as collaborator, I'd rather keep my username in it.

Opening such a reel, clicking the 3 dots, then Tag options, there's a very promising item, "**Hide from my profile**". The problem is, it does not work.

There's also "Stop Sharing" (under the 3 dots) but to my understanding that will remove me from the reel completely.

I perused though [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Instagram/comments/rg6cnt/how_to_remove_collaboration_reel_from_profile/) but didn't find anything that works. It would seem incredible if this is just a bug that's been there for ~2 years, given how visible feature this is.

Any solution or ideas?

[image]

(One detail I noticed is that IG iOS app let's you try "Hide from my profile" only *once*. After clicking "Show in my profile", you no longer see "Hide from my profile" option. IG Android app seems more intuitive in that you can toggle away without losing that option. Still, to clarify, on both platforms "Hide from my profile" ridiculously does not do anything.)